# mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource error in connection with remote mysql DB

Tags: php

My PHP code works well in connecting remote windows system mysql database and returns the output. But, when I'm using the same to connect remote linux system's mysql database, I got the following error:

> "mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in
>   C:\wamp\www\mysqldb.php on line 88"
>
> That line 88 have the following content   "$this->resultQur =
>   mysql_query($query, $this->connID);"

Help me to solve this.

yes. The resource is null in this case. But the same works in windows mysql connection. I got the error only in linux. Need to do any change for linux environment?

While putting "print mysql_error();" i got the following error

"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Comment: After seeing your edit, it looks like the hostname you are provinding is wrong. Is MySQL installed and running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resource you're providing comes from a mysql_connect and that did not succeed!

- Put error reporting on
- Build some basic error handling in your script
- Do not use `mysql_*` but `mysqli_*` or even better `PDO with parameter binding`

Answer (score 0):

Output returned string from [mysql_error()](http://lv.php.net/mysql_error) after your query. In that way you will see actual error.

```
$this->resultQur = mysql_query($query, $this->connID);
print mysql_error();
```

Comment: While putting "print mysql_error();" i got the following error

"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connect returns a resource on success, but a boolean "false" on error.

Your connection attempt probably failed an so the mysql_query won't be successful.

Try  something like the following to see what exactly is causing the error.

`mysql_connect(..) or die(mysql_error());`

Additionally, it seems that the "old" mysql-library get's deprecated in PHP and it's recommended to switch to a more modern version, eg [mysqli](http://ch.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://ch.php.net/PDO).

Answer (score 0):

1 . Firstly put ini_set(‘display_errors’,1);error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); in your code at the start of the page

2 . Put Try catch around the query and print the Exception message

try {   `enter code here`  }catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

3 . Use PDO then the mysql object for query it's a modern and better approach 
Use try catch around the the query and try